# org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

**Command :**

```
\eclipse-SDK-4.2RC3-win32-x86_64_001\eclipse\plugins>java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.0.v20120529-1548.jar -console
```

**Exception (from Log files)**

```
!SESSION 2012-06-22 23:36:27.649 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-06-22 23:36:28.632
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:151)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-06-22 23:36:28.663
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:151)
```

But the following jar is avaialble.

```
org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841.jar
```

Any suggestions on the above error?

Comment: This may help http://www.digizol.com/2013/11/Eclipse-org-osgi-framework-BundleException-equinox-console.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need a couple of bundles installed in order to use the console, and if you launch Equinox using just `java -jar ...` then you will not get those bundles.

The quickest way to get this working is to create a file named `configuration/config.ini` with the following content:

```
osgi.bundles=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20111215-1210.jar@start,file:\org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@start,file:\org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705.jar@start
```

**NB** you will have to review the version numbers of those bundles against what you actually have. I tried this with SDK-4.2M6, it's possible that some of these have changed in RC3.

Answer (score 17):

In the new versions of equinox the built-in OSGi shell has been replaced to the felix gogo shell. If you want to use the new shell you have to place the gogo jars, and define them in your config file.

But, if you liked the OSGi Equinox shell you just have to add the following line to your `config.ini` file to use it: `osgi.console.enable.builtin=true`. In this case no need to add extra jars or any configuration.

Comment: As per [Virtage Devblog](http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/08/osgi-with-equinox-for-beginners-overview/), this property can also be added as a system property e.g. "-Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true"

Comment: This worked to me on Eclipse Kepler adding it as VM arguments in Run configuration, but not when trying to run outside from Eclipse (in this case, accepted answer worked ok).

Answer (score 10):

This is because the default shell of Eclipse has been moved to "Apache Felix Gogo"; so the necessary bundles must be added to the "Run Configuration" before running. Followings are the four bundled that you need to select from the list:

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0v<version>.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0v<version>.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0v<version>.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100<version>.jar
```

[image]

After adding these as shown in the above diagram, the program runs smoothly.

Reference: http://www.digizol.com/2013/11/Eclipse-org-osgi-framework-BundleException-equinox-console.html

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem I've tried to add `osgi.console.enable.builtin=true` in the config.ini file but it seems that the file get recreated every time I run project the way I solve the problem  Run Configurations --> Arguments tab add `-Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true` in the VM Arguments[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Eclipse Helios and Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu Linux. I had the same error on Eclipse Juno and I wasn't able to start Eclipse. **I don't know how but my Java version was decreased to 1.5, which caused the problem**.

In Eclipse Helios, Java 1.5 was causing problem, but I was able to start Eclipse. The error that appeared i Eclipse Helios was:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Loading Web Service DOM...".
```

`org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreEMap$DelegateEObjectContainmentEList`

**Updating the Java version to 1.7 solved the problem**. I guess Eclipse Juno doesn't work with Java 1.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new workspace. To force the workspace window prompt, you need to change the settings in `Eclipse_root_dir\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` and set `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` to true

Answer (score 0):

one of variant is choose another ***java version*** (older then default) , eclipse old version got error when it try to run on **java 9 error**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

i chose **java 8** and all work

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Eclipse_root_dir\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` and change path of `RECENT_WORKSPACES` to some different path.

Comment: This question is very old and already has an accepted answer.  Your answer does not state anything new.