# weird behaviour of eclipse osgi bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to deploy a few bundles I implemented along all the required bundles from Eclipse in order to run my own. Let's say, include the Equinox container also with my bundles so it is like an executable old-school JAR.

That said, when I try to run

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar
```

Nothing happens...it just stays there doing nothing...even if I copy just that bundle to some other place and try the same, nothing happens...is this usual? I mean, I have done this successfully with older versions of this bundle (3.6) and it worked flawlessly.

Alas, I tried -debug flag to see if I could get some output, but only a complain about mission .options file is happening, nothing else.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Doing nothing is the correct behaviour for an OSGi framework that has no bundles installed. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Well, I was expecting this at least "osgi>"....a shell to put it that way, and that is what I get in version 3.6.1...

Comment: So in previous versions, Equinox included a built-in shell, but this made it hard to customise. The shell is now supplied as ordinary bundles, so these must be installed (as you've indicated in your own answer to this question).

Comment: Hi Neil, yes, although based on this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671788/526801 it looks like it is not mandatory to include the apache.gogo bundles to get a console...haven't tried it myself tough...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem...having checked this link: http://docs.codehaus.org/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=82903240, I created the configuration folder, a config.ini in it with the following contents:

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@start, org.eclipse.update.configurator@start,
org.eclipse.core.runtime@start, org.eclipse.core.jobs@start,
org.eclipse.equinox.registry@start, org.eclipse.equinox.preferences@start, 
org.eclipse.core.contenttype@start, org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime@start, 
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell@start, 
org.eclipse.equinox.app@start,org.eclipse.equinox.console@start, 
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
osgi.noShutdown=true
```

This seems to work. I believe this is the minimum set of bundles required to run the Equinox OSGi container...from there, you can use the osgi shell to play with your bundles

Answer (score 0):

You havent included -console option, that is the one that will open up the console view right?