# Cannot start osgi container (equinox) within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I've installed Eclipse Juno Service Release 2. I'm trying to learn OSGi using the Equinox container within eclipse. However, when I try to start Equinox from the command prompt using the following code, it does not start. Can someone please let me know what is missing here?

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar -console
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nope... nothing.. the console prompt simply does not appear while the cursor moves on to the next line.

Comment: I think the OSGi framework exits normally without any application is given. Try to add option '-noExit' to let framework running.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while moving from 3.5 to 3.8.2 . They changed the implementation of console which now relies on [felix gogo project](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-gogo.html).
You will need to start the following bundles along with standard equinox :

1. org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100.v20121001-124408.jar
2. org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201211091412.jar
3. org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar
4. org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar

You can add them to the list of bundles to start by default in the `config.ini` file as follows :

```
#contents of config.ini
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100.v20121001-124408.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201211091412.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar@start
```

Your directory structure should be

```
- org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
- configuration/
             config.ini
```

Comment: Where should I put these jar files in the directory structure?

Comment: at the same level as equinox jar

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I see the same behavior.  After reading some of the beginner tutorial (yes I'm a beginner :-) at 
[OSGi with Equinox for beginners: console, launcher and configuration](http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/08/osgi-with-equinox-for-beginners-overview/) I discovered that logs are sent to log files by default and to see them in stdout you need the -consoleLog paramter

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar -console -consoleLog
```

Which then tells me the message

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
```

I googled that which led me to here: [org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161871/org-osgi-framework-bundleexception-could-not-find-bundle-org-eclipse-equinox-c]).  I didn't try it but it looks like the solution you need.